# Change a unique index to a sparse unique index in mongo db?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, unique-constraint, sparse-matrix

If I have a collection that has a unique index on a field like this:

`collection.User.ensureIndex({username:1}, {unique: true})`

How can I change it so that the index is unique *and* sparse? Running the following doesn't seem to update the index:

`collection.User.ensureIndex({username:1}, {unique: true, sparse:true})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ensureIndex` creates an index on the specified field if the index does not already exist. If you want to change an index, you have to drop the index first and then call `ensureIndex` again with your new options.

```
collection.User.dropIndex("username_1");
collection.User.ensureIndex({username:1}, {unique: true, sparse:true})
```

Taken from the mongodb documentation:

> To add or change index options you must drop the index using the dropIndex() method and issue another ensureIndex() operation with the new options.

Comment: Ah, alright then. That's kinda stupid in this case tho, since adding sparse reduces constraints - the index shouldn't need to be rebuilt. Oh well..